# Internet Connection VMWare Player 6

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, internet, vmware

I am trying to connect to the internet using a Windows 8.1 Host and a Ubuntu 12 LTS Guest in VMWare Player 6.  The internet in the VM is fine if I am hardlined in (its a laptop), but when I go to Wi-Fi I can't connect to anything.

I have tried to change my settings to be bridged (No Success), Bridged with Replicate Physical NEtwork Connection State , and nothing seems to be working.

I have reinstalled the player, that didn't seem to fix it either.

Is there some other setting I can try or configuration?

I can't post an image yet or else I would've included a screenshot of current setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're changing Network Card (between hardlined and wifi) you have to set the default NIC for the mode (NAT, Bridge etc..) to the one you use.

How to do that is documented [Here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/network_configure_ws.html)

Comment: What do you mean set default NIC.  I tried following those directions, and the directions were for Workstation 4, Player doesn't have the same configurations available.  One thing I tried was setting a custom network, then sharing my machines internet connection with that adapter, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Each mode has a default network interface attached to it meaning that if you use NAT you could pass by your wireless adapter to go on the internet while bridge would use your wired adapter. It's been a while since I used player but I'm pretty sure that setting exist, it might just be somewhere else.